# Regular Expression troubles

Tags: c#, regex

I seem to be having trouble with Regular Expressions. I'm trying to get it where the person must enter a first and last name separated by a spaces and only letters are allowed. For the credit card they can only enter digits. I have an idea of the patterns to use, but I'm not sure how to use them exactly.

```
Console.Write("Enter your name for the card: ");
string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
string pattern; 
pattern = ("\b[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\b");
Console.Write("Enter your credit card number: ");
string card = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
pattern = "^[0-9]{12,19}$";
Console.WriteLine("Thank-you for ordering. ");
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string` so you don't need `Convert.ToString`

Comment: Where's the code where you use the patterns?  What results do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: `var rePattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);` then google what to do with it.

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(card, pattern)) {/*valid*/}`

Comment: @juharr I wasn't sure if anyone knew what the pattern for the first and last name separated by a space was. I know that it would be something like `pattern += nfi.(insert patern).ToString() + "\b[a-zA-Z]{2,15}[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\b";`. I tried researching regex, but could find one for that specific function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go. This example should get you started on using Regex in C#.

I've also wrapped `Console.ReadLine()` in `while` loops so the user must enter correct data before moving on.

**You can see the code in action with this [working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IBItTE)**

```
// Get Full Name
string name = "";
while (!Regex.IsMatch(name, @"\b[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,15}\b"))
{
    Console.Write("Enter your name for the card (Firstname Lastname): ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
}

// Get Credit Card Number
string card = "";
while (!Regex.IsMatch(card, "^[0-9]{12,19}$"))
{
    Console.Write("Enter your credit card number: ");
    card = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Thank-you for ordering. ");
Console.Read();
```

Be sure to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to the top of your file.

Comment: This gives me a better idea of what to do. Thank-you for the example. I think I can figure out the rest from here, now that I have a better idea of how regular expressions work.

Comment: Glad I could help! If I have time today I'll edit the answer and clean up the code a bit more also.

Comment: For some reason when someone shows me how it is done, it helps me understand the code better than pages and pages of explanations. So I truly do appreciate your help!

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit for you.

Comment: Thank-you for your help!